# Moment.js Include text in middle of date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a format of "Jan. 27, 2015 at 8:17 AM" that I need to display using moment.js. I'm using the format

```
moment.format('MMM. D, YYYY at h:mm A z');
```

Everything works great except for the word "at". How can I get that word to display as a word instead of the "a" in "at" being translated to the "am/pm". Right now using that date format it ends up looking like this: Jan. 27, 2015 amt 8:17 AM. Notice the "amt" instead of "at".

Is there any simple way of getting it to not process the "a" as part of the format? I have already tried splitting the output and manually entering the "at" after the third space but I'd like a cleaner code if possible.

Answer (score 512, accepted):

[Escape it](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) with square braces

```
moment().format('MMM. D, YYYY [at] h:mm A z');
// produces:    "Jan. 30, 2015 at 2:46 PM "
```

Comment: That did it! I knew there had to be a way :) Thanks

Comment: Just one note, make sure you have space between the custom text and the format tokens

Comment: What if this text is a variable defined as const. Can we include it?

Comment: Is there a way we can add a "space" instead of a word "at"?

Comment: How can you add i18n into the mix and translate `[at]`? So that e.g. `moment().locale('en').format('MMM. D, YYYY [at] h:mm A z');` returns `"Jul. 27, 2020 at 12:54 PM "` whereas `moment().locale('it').format('MMM. D, YYYY [at] h:mm A z');` returns `"lug. 27, 2020 alle 12:54 PM "`? How can we achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Might be a bit late but what I do to work with custom format based on the locale is that I put the moment string format directly into my i18n's locale json, so it will load a different string format based on the language
I suppose another way would be to just create a string out of pieces if your general format is the same, like
'MMM. D, YYYY [at] h:mm A z'
could become
'MMM. D, YYYY [' + i18n('at') + ']  h:mm A z'
or for magic quote user
\`MMM. D, YYYY [${i18n('at')}]  h:mm A z\`