# How to tell momentjs to ignore everything between quotes while formatting?

Tags: momentjs

If a user enter format as 'Q'Q YYYY, the formatted date should ignore the Q in between first and second quote and return the result as Q1 2019 for date 14 Jan 2019.

What the momentjs actually does is ignore quotes or anything that does not mean anything for date formatting and format the others. So what it returns for the above format is... '1'1 2019 for the date 14 Jan 2019.

I can remove quotes but how to tell momentjs to not worry about Q which is in between quotes or anything for that matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js Include text in middle of date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241002/moment-js-include-text-in-middle-of-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need at add [] in your format string. as below.

```
moment().format("'[Q]'Q YYYY");
```

output

```
"'Q'3 2019"
```