# Momentjs format: apply italic text styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using momentjs in reactjs and I want hours of the date as italic. E.g. 18 Feb 20 *11:11*

```
moment().format('DD MMM YY HH:mm')
```

I can create separate date and hours and apply italic styling to hours.
But how can I do the "HH:mm" italic without calculating separate date and hours?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241002/moment-js-include-text-in-middle-of-date-format
Use `moment().format("DD MMM YY [<em>]HH:mm[</em>]")`

Comment: @soktinpk It's not working. It is rendering "<em>"

Answer (score 1):

Square braces will do the job with `<em>` tag.

```
moment().format("DD MMM YY [<em>]HH:mm[</em>]")
```

For more detail about the formatting, You can check on the documentation [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Following is the code which I have tested,

```
var moment = require('moment');
var http = require('http')

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  res.write( moment().format('DD MMM YY [<em>]HH:mm[<em>]'));

  res.end();

}).listen(8000);
```

It outputs as

18 Feb 20  *11:59*

**Edit:** Ok, so if you want to do it on the frontend in reactjs, then you can do it by the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import moment from 'moment'

function App() {
  const date = moment().format('DD MMM YY')
  const hours = moment().format('HH:mm')

  return <div>{date}  
    <span style={{ paddingLeft: '2px' , fontStyle: 'italic' }}>
      {hours}
    </span>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: I'm using **reactjs**  and it is rendering "<em>" as text. Refer my sample code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-meadow-kpgz9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @ShivprasadSambhare I have updated my answer for ReactJS as well, Please check.

Comment: @ShivprasadSambhare Did answer help you?

Comment: Thanks  for help. I wanted it to acheive without calculating separate date and hours. But we can't do that . So I'm going to calculate separate date and hours.

Answer (score 0):

moment.js will not determine the how the date is displayed on your application , it should be done by CSS in your application. Moment js is a javascript library which will help you in calculation of dates and times.
So I advice to calculate hours and minutes separately in span and apply your styles there.